# Regex help to filter only 720p

Tags: regex

I'd like to setup auto download of some Anime using an RSS feed, but only 720p versions. The format never changes and it always looks like below.

[Blahblah] Blahepisode - 12 [720p].mkv

Here is the regex I have come up with but cannot get to work properly.

```
/.\+[720p]+/g
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What language/tool are you using

Comment: Your `.\+[720p]+` matches any char, then a `+`, then 1 or more chars, `7`, `2`, `0` or `p`. Do you want to match `[720]` with regex? Should it match the whole string?

Comment: ruTorrent RSS Manager that allows to filter and exclude.

Also trying to match [720p] so that it downloads just that so I don't get [1080p] versions as well.

Comment: Just escape `[`, `]`, and remove everything else and you're good: `/\[720p\]/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have lines that look like your example, it will be mached with the following Regex:

```
.+(?:\[720p\].mkv)
```

It maches one or more chacacters at start, followed by '[720p].mkv'.

Note that the Square brackets are escaped to '`\[`' and '`\]`', otherwise they have special meaning.

if you only need '`[720p]`' then you can use:

```
\[720p\]
```